# Regex to match a result that isn't single line and expanded across multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, parsing, multiline, php-parser

I want to change `/<\?php\s([\s\S]*?)\?>/gi` the way that single line PHP tags become excluded.

For example, here I want to match only second PHP tag and not the first one:

```
Test number <?PHP echo($a);?> is here.

This is test number <?PHP echo($b);
$b = $a?> that expanded across multiple lines.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
<\?php(?!\S)((?:(?!<\?php(?!\S)|\?>).)*\R[\s\S]*?)\?>
```

A variation with multiline `.`:

```
<\?php\s((?:(?!<\?php\s|\?>).)*\R(?s:.*?))\?>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gj0C9b/6). *Details*:

- `<\?php` - a `<?php` substring
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary (immediately to the right, there must be either a whitespace or start of string)
- `((?:(?!<\?php(?!\S)|\?>).)*\R[\s\S]*?)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:(?!<\?php(?!\S)|\?>).)*` - any single char other than a line break char, zero or more and as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `<?php + a right-hand whitespace boundary or` ?>` char sequence
  - `\R` - a line break sequence
  - `[\s\S]*?` / `(?s:.*?)` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\?>` - a `?>` substring.

Comment: Thanks I used first code, BTW I replaced `\R` with `\n` to work. Also it doesn't match if we have `<?PHP` righ at the end of the line (with no space) and have only one line after that, any suggestions? However I can use an extra regex to match this case.

Comment: @RezaNooralizadeh `\n` is not enough if you have CRLF line endings. The regex [works fine](https://regex101.com/r/gj0C9b/3) if `<?PHP` is at the end of a line.

Comment: In your example, second PHP section has 3 lines but if you remove middle line, it doesn't get matched. BTW I use this regex in addition to the other one: `<\?php\n[\s\S]*?\?>`

Comment: @RezaNooralizadeh Ok, `\s` consumed the newline here and `\R` could not find any match. It is then better to use either a whitespace boundary - `<\?php(?!\s)((?:(?!<\?php\b|\?>).)*\R[\s\S]*?)\?>` - or a word boundary, `<\?php\b((?:(?!<\?php\b|\?>).)*\R[\s\S]*?)\?>`.

Comment: Thanks. Now first code in the edited answer works fine